# System of 3 non-linear equations in 3 unknowns - sum and product of solutions without needing to actually solve?

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetry

Consider three, rather generic, equations in three variables $x,y,z$:
$$
\begin{cases}
y z+x=a\\
z x+y=b\\
x y+z=c
\end{cases}
$$
Now, assuming that there is a solution to this system, is it possible to find an expression in terms of $a,b,c$ only for the sum and/or product of the solutions $x,y,z$?

By this I mean something along the lines of $x+y+z=a+b+c$.

**Edit** I do not mean the system is true for all values $x,y,z$ as was suggested in a comment below, but that it is true for *some* set ${x,y,z}$ and the sum and product of these *specific* values may be expressible in terms of $a,b,c$. Apologies for any confusion...

Some brief experimentation with Mathematica gave me the results $x+y+z=a+b+c$ and $xyz=(a-bc)(b-ca)(c-ab)$ but I'm not sure if this is valid, nor how to make the algebra work to get there.

**Secondly...** if these solutions are valid, does this make the system **symmetric** in the group-theory sense? The original system looks to be only partially symmetric, but the solution sub and product actually looks symmetric. I'm not sure if that is significant.

Comment: I think something went wrong with your use of Mathematica: neither $x+y+z=a+b+c$ nor $xyz=(a-bc)(b-ca)(c-ab)$ hold true for the simple example of $x=y=z=1$ and $a=b=c=2$.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in the original question. I am asking **IF** there is a valid answer for each of x, y and z, then what is the sum and product of these values in terms of a, b, c? Your answer is suggesting a specific case that does not apply.

Comment: Are you saying that there may be another solution for $x,y,z$ when $a=b=c=2$ that does satisfy $x+y+z=a+b+c$?

Comment: I'm not specifying the values of a,b,c at all but I do see your point here: fix a,b,c and then solve for x,y,z... maybe there are restrictions I have not considered.

Comment: Can you share what you did in Mathematica to get the results you did?

Comment: @AlexK - I just used Solve and then defined each solution as a function before adding and using FullSimplify.

Answer (score 2):

Let $e_1=a+b+c,e_2=ab+ca+bc,e_3=abc$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials in $a,b,c$. Then by resultant computations in [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de) I have found that $t=x+y+z$ is the root of a *quintic* with coefficients in $\mathbb Q[e_1,e_2,e_3]$:
$$t^5-e_1t^4+(e_2-4e_1-6)t^3+(4e_1^2-e_3-e_2+14e_1+8)t^2+(-4e_2e_1-8e_1^2+6e_3+3e_2-12e_1-3)t+((e_2+2e_1)^2-3(3e_3+e_2-e_1))=0$$
Adding the three original equations together and subtracting $e_1$ yields $u=xy+zx+yz=e_1-t$. Now the second elementary symmetric function of the original equations' LHSs gives
$$xyz=\frac{e_2-u(t+1)}{t-3}$$

Comment: Thanks - I think this is definitely on the right track. The question is from 1904 (Cambridge University Entrance Examinations training material for students) so I'm not sure about the computations needing to be as complicated as they are, but I definitely think your conclusion is onto something.